# lighttpd setenv.set-response-header is not working as expected

Tags: lighttpd

I have a web server running the latest lighttpd code. The configuration uses `setenv.set-response-header` but the output is different than expected.

A simplified version of the configuration is shown below. All the redirects and rewrites work as configured, but the resulting response does not have the `cache-control` header set to match.

I've tried nesting with `else`, making a flat configuration, moving the `set` to higher/lower tiers. Nothing so far has produced the result I was expecting.

Suggestions gratefully received!

```
  $HTTP["request-method"] == "GET" {

      server.document-root = "/var/www/"

      $HTTP["url"] == "/a" {
  
          setenv.set-response-header = ( 
              "Cache-Control" => "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
          )  

          url.rewrite-once = ( "" => "" )

      } else {

          $HTTP["url"] == "/b" {

              $REQUEST_HEADER["x"] =~ "y" {

                  setenv.set-response-header = ( 
                      "Cache-Control" => "max-age=60, must-revalidate"
                  )  

                  url.rewrite-once = ( "" => "" )

              } else {

                  setenv.set-response-header = ( 
                      "Cache-Control" => "max-age=60, must-revalidate"
                  )  

                  url.rewrite-once = ( "" => "" )

              } 

          } else {
                      
              $HTTP["url"] == "/c" {

                  $REQUEST_HEADER["x"] =~ "y" {

                      url.redirect = ( "" => "" )

                  } else {

                      setenv.set-response-header = ( 
                          "Cache-Control" => "max-age=60, must-revalidate"
                      )  

                      url.rewrite-once = ( "" => "" )

                  }                     
              
              } else {
                          
                  $HTTP["url"] == "/d" {

                      setenv.set-response-header = ( 
                          "Cache-Control" => "max-age=60, must-revalidate"
                      )  

                      url.rewrite-once = ( "" => "" )
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the URL is rewritten using `url.rewrite-once`, then *that* target URL is what lighttpd uses as the request.  When lighttpd serves that request, lighttpd generates a response.  Once the response is generated, that is when `setenv.set-response-header` is applied.

```
$HTTP["url"] == "/rewrite-target" {
    setenv.set-response-header = (
      "Cache-Control" => "max-age=60, must-revalidate"
    )
}
```

The *target* resource is to what the caching headers apply, not to the original request which was rewritten.  Your current placement of `setenv.set-response-header` is not used because those are not the *target* resource.  The *target* resource is the resource after the `url.rewrite-once`.

Comment: If you wish to add a response header to specific initial requests, regardless of `url.rewrite-once`, then you can use [lighttpd mod_magnet](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/mod_magnet)